# Connect-AzAccount: Resource temporarily unavailable (management.azure.com:443)

Tags: azure, powershell

When i try to connect to Azure Portal from within a docker container in my Visual Studio Code i get the following error. I do manage to login directly (meaning outside of a container) and i do not get this error when connecting directly.

***Connect-AzAccount: Resource temporarily unavailable (management.azure.com:443)***

My steps:

1. **docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/azure-powershell pwsh**

PowerShell 7.1.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

2. PS /> **Connect-AzAccount**

WARNING: Interactive authentication is not supported in this session, please run cmdlet 'Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication'.

3. PS /> **Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication**

WARNING: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code xXxXxXxX to authenticate.
Connect-AzAccount: Resource temporarily unavailable (management.azure.com:443)

My settings:

**docker --version**

Docker version 20.10.3, build 48d30b5

**$PSVersionTable**

PSVersion                      7.1.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.1.1
OS                             Linux 5.4.0-65-generic #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

**Visual Studio Code**

Version: 1.53.2
Commit: 622cb03f7e070a9670c94bae1a45d78d7181fbd4
Date: 2021-02-11T11:48:44.518Z
Electron: 11.2.1
Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
Node.js: 12.18.3
V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-65-generic snap

**DEBUG STREAM**
(to turn on debug stream > $DebugPreference='Continue')

In below debug stream you can see "WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations'"

And i dont know why it mentions the name 'organisations'

```
DEBUG: Request [9c3c6727-80c8-4d11-b20f-070348b3d84c] POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token
x-client-SKU:REDACTED
x-client-Ver:REDACTED
x-client-OS:REDACTED
x-client-current-telemetry:REDACTED
x-client-last-telemetry:REDACTED
x-ms-PKeyAuth:REDACTED
x-ms-lib-capability:REDACTED
client-request-id:REDACTED
return-client-request-id:REDACTED
x-app-name:REDACTED
x-app-ver:REDACTED
x-ms-client-request-id:9c3c6727-80c8-4d11-b20f-070348b3d84c
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Identity/1.4.0-beta.1,(.NET 5.0.2; Linux 5.4.0-65-generic #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021)
client assembly: Azure.Identity
DEBUG: Response [9c3c6727-80c8-4d11-b20f-070348b3d84c] 200 OK (00.1s)
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security:REDACTED
X-Content-Type-Options:REDACTED
P3P:REDACTED
client-request-id:REDACTED
x-ms-request-id:REDACTED
x-ms-ests-server:REDACTED
x-ms-clitelem:REDACTED
Set-Cookie:REDACTED
Date:Fri, 26 Feb 2021 10:23:21 GMT
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires:-1
Content-Length:4977

DEBUG: DeviceCodeCredential.Authenticate succeeded. Scopes: [ https://management.core.windows.net//.default ] ParentRequestId:  ExpiresOn: 2021-02-26T11:23:21.0000000+00:00
DEBUG: DeviceCodeCredential.GetToken invoked. Scopes: [ https://management.core.windows.net//.default ] ParentRequestId: 
DEBUG: DeviceCodeCredential.GetToken succeeded. Scopes: [ https://management.core.windows.net//.default ] ParentRequestId:  ExpiresOn: 2021-02-26T11:23:21.0000000+00:00
DEBUG: ============================ HTTP REQUEST ============================

HTTP Method:
GET

Absolute Uri:
https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2019-06-01

Headers:
x-ms-client-request-id        : ebb8a1f7-5baf-44e9-a7d3-835347962742
Accept-Language               : en-US

Body:



WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations'
Connect-AzAccount: Resource temporarily unavailable (management.azure.com:443)
DEBUG: AzureQoSEvent: CommandName - Connect-AzAccount; IsSuccess - False; Duration - 00:01:16.3205825; Exception - System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable (management.azure.com:443)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Factories.CancelRetryHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Version2019_06_01.TenantsOperations.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Version2019_06_01.TenantsOperationsExtensions.ListAsync(ITenantsOperations operations, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Version2019_06_01.TenantsOperationsExtensions.List(ITenantsOperations operations)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.Paging.GenericPageEnumerator`1..ctor(Func`1 list, Func`2 listNext, UInt64 first, UInt64 skip)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.Paging.GenericPageEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.Utilities.Version2019_06_01.SubscriptionClientWrapper.ListAccountTenants(IAccessToken accessToken, IAzureEnvironment environment)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.SubscriptionClientProxy.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<ListAccountTenants>b__0(ISubscriptionClientWrapper client)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.SubscriptionClientProxy.<>c.<.ctor>b__2_0(Action`1 subscriptionClientAction, LoggerWriter warning)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.SubscriptionClientProxy.ListAccountTenants(IAccessToken accessToken, IAzureEnvironment environment)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient.ListAccountTenants(IAzureAccount account, IAzureEnvironment environment, SecureString password, String promptBehavior, Action`1 promptAction)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient.Login(IAzureAccount account, IAzureEnvironment environment, String tenantId, String subscriptionId, String subscriptionName, SecureString password, Boolean skipValidation, Action`1 promptAction, String name, Boolean shouldPopulateContextList, Int32 maxContextPopulation)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.<>c__DisplayClass111_2.<ExecuteCmdlet>b__4()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.<>c__DisplayClass111_0.<ExecuteCmdlet>b__1(AzureRmProfile localProfile, RMProfileClient profileClient, String name)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.<>c__DisplayClass118_0.<SetContextWithOverwritePrompt>b__0(AzureRmProfile prof, RMProfileClient client)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Common.AzureContextModificationCmdlet.ModifyContext(Action`2 contextAction)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.SetContextWithOverwritePrompt(Action`3 setContextAction)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.<>c__3`1.<ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob>b__3_0(T c)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet, Action`1 executor)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord();
DEBUG: Finish sending metric.
DEBUG: 10:23:28 AM - ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand end processing.
PS />
```

```
PS /> Get-Module  -ListAvailable

    Directory: /usr/local/share/powershell/Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Script     5.5.0                 Az                                  Core,Desk 
Script     2.2.5                 Az.Accounts                         Core,Desk {Disable-AzDataCollection, Disable-AzContextAutosave, Enable-AzDataCollection, Enable-AzContextAutosave…}
Script     1.1.1                 Az.Advisor                          Core,Desk {Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation, Enable-AzAdvisorRecommendation, Disable-AzAdvisorRecommendation, Get-AzAdvisorConfi…
Script     2.0.2                 Az.Aks                              Core,Desk {Get-AzAksCluster, New-AzAksCluster, Remove-AzAksCluster, Import-AzAksCredential…}
Script     1.1.4                 Az.AnalysisServices                 Core,Desk {Resume-AzAnalysisServicesServer, Suspend-AzAnalysisServicesServer, Get-AzAnalysisServicesServer, Remove-AzAnalys…
Script     2.2.0                 Az.ApiManagement                    Core,Desk {Add-AzApiManagementApiToGateway, Add-AzApiManagementApiToProduct, Add-AzApiManagementProductToGroup, Add-AzApiMa…
Script     1.0.0                 Az.AppConfiguration                 Core,Desk {Get-AzAppConfigurationStore, Get-AzAppConfigurationStoreKey, New-AzAppConfigurationStore, New-AzAppConfiguration…
Script     1.1.0                 Az.ApplicationInsights              Core,Desk {Get-AzApplicationInsights, New-AzApplicationInsights, Remove-AzApplicationInsights, Update-AzApplicationInsights…
Script     1.4.3                 Az.Automation                       Core,Desk {Get-AzAutomationHybridWorkerGroup, Remove-AzAutomationHybridWorkerGroup, Get-AzAutomationJobOutputRecord, Import…
Script     3.1.0                 Az.Batch                            Core,Desk {Remove-AzBatchAccount, Get-AzBatchAccount, Get-AzBatchAccountKey, New-AzBatchAccount…}
Script     2.0.0                 Az.Billing                          Core,Desk {Get-AzBillingInvoice, Get-AzBillingPeriod, Get-AzEnrollmentAccount, Get-AzConsumptionBudget…}
Script     1.6.0                 Az.Cdn                              Core,Desk {Get-AzCdnProfile, Get-AzCdnProfileSsoUrl, New-AzCdnProfile, Remove-AzCdnProfile…}
Script     1.8.0                 Az.CognitiveServices                Core,Desk {Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccount, Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccountKey, Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccountSku, Get-AzCogn…
Script     4.9.0                 Az.Compute                          Core,Desk {Remove-AzAvailabilitySet, Get-AzAvailabilitySet, New-AzAvailabilitySet, Update-AzAvailabilitySet…}
Script     1.0.3                 Az.ContainerInstance                Core,Desk {New-AzContainerGroup, Get-AzContainerGroup, Remove-AzContainerGroup, Get-AzContainerInstanceLog}
Script     2.2.0                 Az.ContainerRegistry                Core,Desk {New-AzContainerRegistry, Get-AzContainerRegistry, Update-AzContainerRegistry, Remove-AzContainerRegistry…}
Script     1.0.0                 Az.CosmosDB                         Core,Desk {Get-AzCosmosDBSqlContainer, Get-AzCosmosDBSqlContainerThroughput, Get-AzCosmosDBSqlDatabase, Get-AzCosmosDBSqlDa…
Script     1.1.0                 Az.DataBoxEdge                      Core,Desk {Get-AzDataBoxEdgeJob, Get-AzDataBoxEdgeDevice, Invoke-AzDataBoxEdgeDevice, New-AzDataBoxEdgeDevice…}
Script     1.1.0                 Az.Databricks                       Core,Desk {Get-AzDatabricksVNetPeering, Get-AzDatabricksWorkspace, New-AzDatabricksVNetPeering, New-AzDatabricksWorkspace…}
Script     1.11.3                Az.DataFactory                      Core,Desk {Set-AzDataFactoryV2, Update-AzDataFactoryV2, Get-AzDataFactoryV2, Remove-AzDataFactoryV2…}
Script     1.0.2                 Az.DataLakeAnalytics                Core,Desk {Get-AzDataLakeAnalyticsDataSource, New-AzDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogCredential, Remove-AzDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogCr…
Script     1.3.0                 Az.DataLakeStore                    Core,Desk {Get-AzDataLakeStoreTrustedIdProvider, Remove-AzDataLakeStoreTrustedIdProvider, Remove-AzDataLakeStoreFirewallRul…
Script     1.0.0                 Az.DataShare                        Core,Desk {New-AzDataShareAccount, Get-AzDataShareAccount, Remove-AzDataShareAccount, New-AzDataShare…}
Script     1.1.0                 Az.DeploymentManager                Core,Desk {Get-AzDeploymentManagerArtifactSource, New-AzDeploymentManagerArtifactSource, Set-AzDeploymentManagerArtifactSou…
Script     2.1.1                 Az.DesktopVirtualization            Core,Desk {Disconnect-AzWvdUserSession, Expand-AzWvdMsixImage, Get-AzWvdApplication, Get-AzWvdApplicationGroup…}
Script     1.0.2                 Az.DevTestLabs                      Core,Desk {Get-AzDtlAllowedVMSizesPolicy, Get-AzDtlAutoShutdownPolicy, Get-AzDtlAutoStartPolicy, Get-AzDtlVMsPerLabPolicy…}
Script     1.1.2                 Az.Dns                              Core,Desk {Get-AzDnsRecordSet, New-AzDnsRecordConfig, Remove-AzDnsRecordSet, Set-AzDnsRecordSet…}
Script     1.3.0                 Az.EventGrid                        Core,Desk {New-AzEventGridTopic, Get-AzEventGridTopic, Set-AzEventGridTopic, New-AzEventGridTopicKey…}
Script     1.7.1                 Az.EventHub                         Core,Desk {New-AzEventHubNamespace, Get-AzEventHubNamespace, Set-AzEventHubNamespace, Remove-AzEventHubNamespace…}
Script     1.7.0                 Az.FrontDoor                        Core,Desk {New-AzFrontDoor, Get-AzFrontDoor, Set-AzFrontDoor, Remove-AzFrontDoor…}
Script     2.0.0                 Az.Functions                        Core,Desk {Get-AzFunctionApp, Get-AzFunctionAppAvailableLocation, Get-AzFunctionAppPlan, Get-AzFunctionAppSetting…}
Script     4.2.0                 Az.HDInsight                        Core,Desk {Get-AzHDInsightJob, New-AzHDInsightSqoopJobDefinition, Wait-AzHDInsightJob, New-AzHDInsightStreamingMapReduceJob…
Script     1.2.0                 Az.HealthcareApis                   Core,Desk {New-AzHealthcareApisService, Remove-AzHealthcareApisService, Set-AzHealthcareApisService, Get-AzHealthcareApisSe…
Script     2.7.2                 Az.IotHub                           Core,Desk {Add-AzIotHubKey, Get-AzIotHubEventHubConsumerGroup, Get-AzIotHubConnectionString, Get-AzIotHubJob…}
Script     3.4.0                 Az.KeyVault                         Core,Desk {Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate, Update-AzKeyVaultCertificate, Stop-AzKeyVaultCertificateOperation, Get-AzKeyVaultCert…
Script     1.0.1                 Az.Kusto                            Core,Desk {Add-AzKustoClusterLanguageExtension, Add-AzKustoDatabasePrincipal, Get-AzKustoAttachedDatabaseConfiguration, Get…
Script     1.5.0                 Az.LogicApp                         Core,Desk {Get-AzIntegrationAccountAgreement, Get-AzIntegrationAccountAssembly, Get-AzIntegrationAccountBatchConfiguration,…
Script     1.1.3                 Az.MachineLearning                  Core,Desk {Move-AzMlCommitmentAssociation, Get-AzMlCommitmentAssociation, Get-AzMlCommitmentPlanUsageHistory, Remove-AzMlCo…
Script     1.1.0                 Az.Maintenance                      Core,Desk {Get-AzApplyUpdate, Get-AzConfigurationAssignment, Get-AzMaintenanceConfiguration, Get-AzMaintenanceUpdate…}
Script     2.0.0                 Az.ManagedServices                  Core,Desk {Get-AzManagedServicesAssignment, New-AzManagedServicesAssignment, Remove-AzManagedServicesAssignment, Get-AzMana…
Script     1.0.2                 Az.MarketplaceOrdering              Core,Desk {Get-AzMarketplaceTerms, Set-AzMarketplaceTerms}
Script     1.1.1                 Az.Media                            Core,Desk {Sync-AzMediaServiceStorageKey, Set-AzMediaServiceKey, Get-AzMediaServiceKey, Get-AzMediaServiceNameAvailability…}
Script     2.4.0                 Az.Monitor                          Core,Desk {Get-AzMetricDefinition, Get-AzMetric, Remove-AzLogProfile, Get-AzLogProfile…}
Script     4.6.0                 Az.Network                          Core,Desk {Add-AzApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate, Get-AzApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate, New-AzAppl…
Script     1.1.1                 Az.NotificationHubs                 Core,Desk {Get-AzNotificationHub, Get-AzNotificationHubAuthorizationRule, Get-AzNotificationHubListKey, Get-AzNotificationH…
Script     2.3.0                 Az.OperationalInsights              Core,Desk {New-AzOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource, New-AzOperationalInsightsCustomLogDataSource, Disable-AzOpe…
Script     1.4.1                 Az.PolicyInsights                   Core,Desk {Get-AzPolicyEvent, Get-AzPolicyState, Get-AzPolicyStateSummary, Get-AzPolicyRemediation…}
Script     1.1.2                 Az.PowerBIEmbedded                  Core,Desk {Remove-AzPowerBIWorkspaceCollection, Get-AzPowerBIWorkspaceCollection, Get-AzPowerBIWorkspaceCollectionAccessKey…
Script     1.0.3                 Az.PrivateDns                       Core,Desk {Get-AzPrivateDnsZone, Remove-AzPrivateDnsZone, Set-AzPrivateDnsZone, New-AzPrivateDnsZone…}
Script     3.4.0                 Az.RecoveryServices                 Core,Desk {Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProperty, Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault, Get-AzRecoveryServicesVaultSettingsFile, New-…
Script     1.4.0                 Az.RedisCache                       Core,Desk {Remove-AzRedisCachePatchSchedule, New-AzRedisCacheScheduleEntry, Get-AzRedisCachePatchSchedule, New-AzRedisCache…
Script     1.0.3                 Az.Relay                            Core,Desk {New-AzRelayNamespace, Get-AzRelayNamespace, Set-AzRelayNamespace, Remove-AzRelayNamespace…}
Script     3.2.1                 Az.Resources                        Core,Desk {Get-AzProviderOperation, Remove-AzRoleAssignment, Get-AzRoleAssignment, New-AzRoleAssignment…}
Script     1.4.1                 Az.ServiceBus                       Core,Desk {New-AzServiceBusNamespace, Get-AzServiceBusNamespace, Set-AzServiceBusNamespace, Remove-AzServiceBusNamespace…}
Script     2.2.2                 Az.ServiceFabric                    Core,Desk {Add-AzServiceFabricClientCertificate, Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate, Add-AzServiceFabricNode, Add-AzServ…
Script     1.2.0                 Az.SignalR                          Core,Desk {New-AzSignalR, Get-AzSignalR, Get-AzSignalRKey, New-AzSignalRKey…}
Script     2.16.0                Az.Sql                              Core,Desk {Get-AzSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption, Get-AzSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryptionActivity, Set-AzSqlDatabas…
Script     1.1.0                 Az.SqlVirtualMachine                Core,Desk {New-AzSqlVM, Get-AzSqlVM, Update-AzSqlVM, Remove-AzSqlVM…}
Script     3.3.0                 Az.Storage                          Core,Desk {Get-AzStorageAccount, Get-AzStorageAccountKey, New-AzStorageAccount, New-AzStorageAccountKey…}
Script     1.4.0                 Az.StorageSync                      Core,Desk {Invoke-AzStorageSyncCompatibilityCheck, New-AzStorageSyncService, Get-AzStorageSyncService, Set-AzStorageSyncSer…
Script     1.0.1                 Az.StreamAnalytics                  Core,Desk {Get-AzStreamAnalyticsFunction, Get-AzStreamAnalyticsDefaultFunctionDefinition, New-AzStreamAnalyticsFunction, Re…
Script     1.0.0                 Az.Support                          Core,Desk {Get-AzSupportService, Get-AzSupportProblemClassification, Get-AzSupportTicket, Get-AzSupportTicketCommunication…}
Script     1.0.4                 Az.TrafficManager                   Core,Desk {Add-AzTrafficManagerCustomHeaderToEndpoint, Remove-AzTrafficManagerCustomHeaderFromEndpoint, Add-AzTrafficManage…
Script     2.3.0                 Az.Websites                         Core,Desk {Get-AzAppServicePlan, Set-AzAppServicePlan, New-AzAppServicePlan, Remove-AzAppServicePlan…}

    Directory: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Manifest   1.2.5                 Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive        Desk      {Compress-Archive, Expand-Archive}
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Host           Core      {Start-Transcript, Stop-Transcript}
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     Core      {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-ItemProperty, Join-Path…}
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       Core      {Get-Credential, Get-ExecutionPolicy, Set-ExecutionPolicy, ConvertFrom-SecureString…}
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        Core      {Export-Alias, Get-Alias, Import-Alias, New-Alias…}
Script     1.4.7                 PackageManagement                   Desk      {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-PackageSource…}
Script     2.2.5                 PowerShellGet                       Desk      {Find-Command, Find-DSCResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCapability…}
Script     2.0.5                 PSDesiredStateConfiguration         Core      {Configuration, New-DscChecksum, Get-DscResource, Invoke-DscResource}
Script     2.1.0                 PSReadLine                          Desk      {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption…}
Binary     2.0.3                 ThreadJob                           Desk      Start-ThreadJob
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just deleted the 2 extra Tenants i had created for training purposes.

The issue is now solved for me and i can login again via Powershell from within a Docker container

PS /> Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication